# sqlplus through shell script

Tags: shell, sqlplus

When using `sqlplus  $SPTCEP01` in the shell script i am getting  below error

```
pwd=ar#admin#

SPTCEP01='ARAD/$pwd@XYZ'
Usage: SQLPLUS [ [<option>] [<logon>] [<start>] ]
where <option> ::= -H | -V | [ [-L] [-M <o>] [-R <n>] [-S] ]
      <logon>  ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_string>] | / | /NOLOG
      <start>  ::= @<URI>|<filename>[.<ext>] [<parameter> ...]
        "-H" displays the SQL*Plus version banner and usage syntax
        "-V" displays the SQL*Plus version banner
        "-L" attempts log on just once
        "-M <o>" uses HTML markup options <o>
        "-R <n>" uses restricted mode <n>
        "-S" uses silent mode
```

however when i am using 'sqlplus ARAD@XYZ' and entering password manually it letting me connect to the DB.
It seem the special characters in the pwd are causing issue. tried using escape charaters () also

```
pwd=ar\#admin\#
```

then also its not letting me connect to db through script. I cannot change the password.

Comment: Which shell, and how are you actually calling SQL\*Plus in your script - you've left that line out...

Comment: apologies,@AlexPoole I am using Korn Shell

Comment: OK, which version, and which operating system? I don't have a problem in 88 or 93, on Linux or Solaris. Please add your actual call to the question too though, in case you're doing something odd there. (The answer is probably going to involve double-quotes, but I'd like to be able to replicate and test...)

Comment: @AlexPoole OS is HP-UX